# Is there a formal way to ask for feedback on editing specific old questions?

Tags: support, questions, edits, reputation, editing-help

I'm going through my old negatively voted questions to try to improve them, and I'd like to ask some experienced users for advice. My first approach was to add a comment to them asking for possible ways to improve them, but, reasonably, this didn't catch much attention.

Is there an intended way to ask the community for feedback on specific old questions?

This applies to answered questions too, as the main objective is to improve the quality of the question itself.

Comment: Eh, Meta is an OK way to do so - certainly helps bring more eyes to posts (might backfire a little as per Meta effect, but definitely a way to get suggestions)

Comment: I think the [meta-tag:support] tag is not appropriate. If you want more answer, you can add [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), if you just want to improve it you can just ask it on meta such as Oleg said.

Comment: Thank you. In that case, the support tag would still be the most appropriate one, right?

Comment: support: "A request for assistance with one of the site's features." - so not really (don't ask me which one would be better)

Comment: [discussion] is fine, so is [support] -- the site's feature being "asking questions".

Comment: Meta is the way. There are oodles of existing questions about improving questions on meta already by the way, you might want to do a little research first to see what kind of response you can expect. It can be quite an experience to receive help from 10+ people at the exact same time.